# Where can I purchase this item

Tags: wo2009048895a2, nut, allergy

In reference to the patent: [WO2009048895A2](https://www.google.com/patents/WO2009048895A2)

is this device in production or where can I purchase an item.

thanks

reason I am asking is that I have a nut allergy

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a patent application, not yet a patent. It may never get to be a patent. Either way, the existence of a patent doesn't necessarily imply there is a marketed product. Many, if not most, patents never get realized as products. That said, there are definitely products for testing for allergens. I recommend that you do a Google search for "nut allergen testing" and you should find quite a few hits. For instance this one: http://foodsafety.neogen.com/en/reveal-for-multi-treenut, or this one: https://www.romerlabs.com/en/en/products/test-kits/food-allergen-test-kits/. I don't know if these are marketed to home users or not. Look for the term "lateral flow strips". These are simple devices that work like home pregnancy test strips.

Comment: I realize this isn't a good question, but at the time I attempted to answer it it wasn't on hold. I think my answer is informative. If there is a reason for the down vote I would prefer to hear it so I can improve the answer.